Libcrypto.so.3 missing after `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`
After updating from Ubuntu 23.10 to Ubuntu 24.04 ltd - libcrypto.so.3 is missing.
Running sudo - following error:
sudo: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Upgrade seem to break on update of Thunderbird snap.
Tried to boot in single user aka recovery mode. But that just made my kernel start with a kernel panic.
Error:
2: clearing orphaned inode 262366 034-8, gia, mode=910BRES, Sizeーベルトコン

nomen1p2: Clearing orphaned inode 924388 (uid-0, gid=0, mode-0100644, size-776289

nomen1p2: clean, 3705314/31227904 files, 65639625/124895488 blocks

init: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.3: cannot open shared object file

2.150218] Kernel panic not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00 2.150229] CPU: 8 PID: 1 Conn: init Not tainted 6.5.0-28-generic #29-Ubuntu

2.150240] Hardware name: LENOVO 20M9002HMX/20M9002HMX, BIOS M2CET700 (1.533 03/11/2024

2.150250] Call Trace:

2.150256] <TASK>

2.150262] dump_stack_lul+0x48/0x70

2.150271]

dump_stack+0x10/0x20

2.1502771

panic+0x1bb/0x3a0

do_exit+0x6a1/0x610

2.1502861

Stack trace phone image
Next step is USB boot to see what I can recover.
(Sorry for the badly formatted post - written from my phone)

Same problem here, older system upgraded through several versions, updating from 23.10, on an older Dell XPS

Have you tried installing libssl-dev? https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libcrypto.so&mode=exactfilename&suite=noble&arch=any

One note here: I also saw the libcrypto.so.3 error in the update log, and had to reboot right after it said "upgrade finished with errors" as most applications stopped working (e.g. no opening new terminal windows). The kernel has seemingly not been updated, it is still on 6.5, and none of the old kernels (recovery mode or not) can boot.

Update: booting from USB stick, bind-mounting and running an apt dist-upgrade in chroot fixed the install, works now

@moo I did try to install packages with the file, but had a hard time doing it since sudo did not work, and I did not have root permission on my user. So no luck.

@VolkA If you got it working on you setup with the method you mentioned above. Please add that as a solution to the problem, maybe with a bit more detail. Then I can upvote that solution. I ended up starting for USB and creating backup and then did a fresh installation. So can check if the solution you mentioned would work for me, but maybe other. Thanks

I hit same failure when updating to Xubuntu 24.04.
From Ubuntu release notes upgrades (at this moment) are not supported, and if you hit a problem, probably best solution is to use a live cd/pen to do a backup and restore it after a fresh install.
I followed a different path, following some advice on comments to the question I tried my luck with chroot.
This is a receipt for my case, not guarantees that will work for you.

Boot live cd and configure network
mount / folder on live cd (root disk)
On root disk, cd  "root disk"

rm dev/null
cp /etc/resolv.cnf etc/resolv.cnf


sudo chroot . /bin/bash -c "apt --fix-broken install"

After all updates are done, reboot shall work.
Log in and execute:

sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade

Just a reminder, do a backup before executing this commands.

I'm on kubuntu. My do-release-upgrade installation failed with the libcrypto.so.3 error (I couldn't sudo and couldnt mount a usb drive) and this left my laptop unusable.
i took a photo on my phone of Nine's instruction, kicked off a live usb boot and got it all working following these instructions off my phone. Worked perfectly.. Brilliant - thankyou @Nine!

If you come across this error and have not yet shut down your computer, you can fix it using pkexec instead of sudo. This will create a graphical "Authentication Required" window for the password, instead of taking the password in the terminal.
pkexec apt --fix-broken install
However, pkexec won't remember you've recently authenticated like sudo does. (It's for authorizing one specific command.) If the above doesn't work and you need additional troubleshooting, it may be useful to pkexec sh so you can more easily do multiple commands as the super user.
If you've already shut down and Linux can't boot up, you'll need a bootable CD or USB to rescue the system. See the answer by @Nine.
